# How to animate a view outside of ScrollView based on it's scroll amount?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Consider simplified layout like this

```swift
ZStack {
  CustomHeaderView()
  ScrollView {
    CustomContentView()
  }
  CustomFooterView()
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to apply animation / scale effect to `CustomHeaderView` based on amount that was scrolled in `ScrollView`.

I was able to find a `.scrollTransition` modifier doc, but it seems like it serves different purpose to basically detect if view is within visible viewport or not, which is not exactly what I am after.

Ideally I was hoping for something like this (but it doesn't seem that such api exists)

```swift
@State private var scroll = CGPoint.zero

ScrollView { 
  // ...
}
.onScroll { data in
  // Grab vertical scroll data to set state "scroll"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out with SwiftUI you happen to (almost) have superpowers nowadays. You could do something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Animating view")
                .scaleEffect(scale)
        }
        .onScroll { scroll in
            Text("Any View Here")
                /// Listens for changes in the scroll view
                .onChange(of: scroll) { oldValue, newValue in
                    withAnimation {
                        scale = max(newValue, 1)
                    }
                }
        }

    }
    
}

extension View {
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func onScroll(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping (CGFloat) -> some View) -> some View {
        ScrollView {
            GeometryReader { geom in
                let size = geom
                let minY = geom.frame(in: .named("SCROLL")).minY
                content(minY)
                /// For the purpose of this example I'm going to make this invisible
                    .hidden()
                self
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .coordinateSpace(.named("SCROLL"))
    }
    
}
```

Tell me if this is what you have been looking for!